# Finding some text in individual cells Google sheets array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I am trying to understand whether E column's any keywords available on C column people Title or not. But  it is not working.

This is my formula

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(E$2:E$1000,MAX(IF(ISERROR(find(E$2:E$1000,C2)),-1,1)*(ROW(E$2:E$1000)-ROW(E$2)+1))))
```

[image]

this is output i'm expecting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try in D2:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, E2:E)))
```

Comment: It showing error https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1HYqmLYuIvGbYrpE6W67A-QxGKcJ74CAykAsqfWtzb_w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SohelAhamed you used double `==`

Comment: It works. But it takes partial text. For example, Title have International, and keyword have Intern. Formula repeats me Intern. Pls help to get it fixed as like exact match word.

Comment: Pls see image https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1gkQ1eOfupBeAnkHjQC97ALNKvHSS5l3v6BkqMUSrMX4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SohelAhamed try: `=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(E2:E, 1, 0))))`